# Items saved to Desktop do not show on Desktop

Tags: finder, desktop

I use Safari and Chrome to download files and set the Desktop as the download folder.

Each time I download something it does not appear on the Desktop. But if I relaunch Finder then it will appear on the Desktop. I relaunch Finder 20-50 times per day.

This behavior existed on High Sierra and now on Mojave. Always using release software, never beta software on this machine.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you access your desktop, and do you have more than one desktop

Comment: One desktop. And I have a hot corner to show desktop so I can get to stuff there.

Comment: I suspect that *somehow* this is related to me not using iCloud, and people at Apple literally never expecting that anybody will ever not use iCloud.